# How can I try my code work on my phone?

Tags: ios, css, html, responsive, iphone-6

I'm working on a website and I have the HTML5 and CSS3 in my laptop and still didn't host it. Is there any way to open my HTML file from my phone 6 eventough it's not hosted?

Comment: Go onto google chrome, open devtools, then click the phone icon in the top-left corner.

Answer (score 1):

if if understood right you mean watching your html  page in your cellphone if you have XAMPP you gotta puts your html into the folder htdocs in xampp then you gotta get the ip from you computer and in a browser in your cell you have to do this ip:port/page.hml an example is this were my ip 192.168.2.251:80/index.html also you gotta be connected in the same network

Comment: Thanks I will try that!